# How to drop ee.Image properties?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to drop some properties of an image in Google Earth Engine, but I just can't figure it out.

Things I've tried:

```
var palsarForest = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF').aside(print,"original palsar")
                  .filterDate('2007-01-01', '2007-12-31')
                  .map(function(image){return image}) // I know it doesn't do anything, but I hoped it will drop all properties
                  .first()
                  .remap([1], [1]) // keep 1 = forest
                  .select(["remapped"],["forest"]).aside(print,"final palsar")
                  .set('system:index',null).aside(print,"after set")
palsarForest = palsarForest
  .copyProperties({'source':palsarForest, 'exclude':['system:index']})
  .aside(print,"after copyProperties")
```

None of my attempts above worked, although the last one should have worked according to the documentation:

> The list of properties to exclude when copying all properties. Must
> not be specified if properties is.

I know I could just ignore those properties, but the image above will be included in an image collection and it just doesn't feel right for each image to have its own properties that are not available for the rest of the images in the collection.

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this question without even commenting, if not because I didn't accept a silly 1 character revision?

Answer (score 3):

Someone else might correct me, but as far as I know, you cannot remove properties. Only add them or set them to `null`. I've noticed that `null` properties tend to go away after certain types of operations. If you really want to get rid of properties, you can create a new image, then add back the original image bands, and finally add back the properties you are interested in. Here are some ways to do that:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF')
  .filterDate('2007-01-01', '2007-12-31')
  .first()
var withoutSomeProps = ee.Image([]) // Image without any bands or properties
  .addBands(image) // At this point you have your image without any properties
  // .copyProperties(image) // Include all but system properties
  // .copyProperties({source: image, properties: ['fnf_class_names']}) // Include specific properties
  // .copyProperties({source: image, exclude: ['system:index']}) // Exclude specific properties  
  // .copyProperties({ // Include properties matching filter
  //   source: image,
  //   properties: image.propertyNames().filter(
  //     ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('item', 'system:')
  //   )
  // })
  // .copyProperties({ // Exclude properties matching filter
  //   source: image,
  //   exclude: image.propertyNames().filter(
  //     ee.Filter.or(
  //       ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('item', 'system:'),
  //       ee.Filter.stringEndsWith('item', '_palette')
  //     )
  //   )
  // })
print(withoutSomeProps)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/947d2cd4d50ee8802037cad100a154e1

Answer (score 1):

> .map(function(image){return image}) // I know it doesn't do anything, but I hoped it will drop all properties

A simple mathematical or boolean operation may help you to drop all properties, e.g. `.map(function(image){return image.multiply(1)})`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing goes away with copyProperties because it's additive; you're copying properties from an image to itself, and it already has those properties.

Just setting them to null should make them go away when you Export the result.