# Removing property from Image Collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have this image collection:

```
ImageCollection (33 elements)
type: ImageCollection
bands: []
features: List (33 elements)
0: Image (1 band)
type: Image
bands: List (1 element)
properties: Object (4 properties)
count: 1
month: 3
system:index: 2
year: 2013
1: Image (1 band)
2: Image (1 band)
3: Image (1 band)
4: Image (1 band)
5: Image (1 band)
6: Image (1 band)
7: Image (1 band)
8: Image (1 band)
9: Image (1 band)
10: Image (1 band)
11: Image (1 band)
12: Image (1 band)
13: Image (1 band)
14: Image (1 band)
15: Image (1 band)
16: Image (1 band)
17: Image (1 band)
18: Image (1 band)
19: Image (1 band)
20: Image (1 band)
21: Image (1 band)
22: Image (1 band)
23: Image (1 band)
24: Image (1 band)
25: Image (1 band)
26: Image (1 band)
27: Image (1 band)
28: Image (1 band)
29: Image (1 band)
30: Image (1 band)
31: Image (1 band)
32: Image (1 band)
```

And I want to remove the property `'count':1` .

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Though it's about images, not collections, the same applies: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403372/how-to-drop-ee-image-properties/403410#403410

Comment: I tried that but it gave me this error: Image.addBands: Parameter 'srcImg' is required.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Wiell suggested, I used the same method proposed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403372/how-to-drop-ee-image-properties/403410#403410) to [How to drop ee.Image properties?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403372/how-to-drop-ee-image-properties).

Here is the code:

```
var newCol = function(image){
return ee.Image([]).addBands(image)
                    .copyProperties({source: image, exclude: ['count']})}


var monthly_sowing_Avg2 = monthly_sowing_Avg.map(newCol)
```